# How to build this simple vector in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python and I want to create an array which has 0.00 has first element, and then adds 0.01 for its next elements until the last one is less than or equal to a given number (in my case 0.55).

In Matlab the code for it would be `(0: 0.01: 0.55)`

And the result would be: `[0.00, 0.01, 0.02, ... , 0.55]`

Now of course I think it can be done really easily in Python with a loop, but I'm wondering if there is a direct way to achieve this with a NumPy function

I tried arange but failed, maybe it's not the right one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Milan mentioned, my first thought was to use `np.arange(0, 0.55, 0.01)` but I just ran it, and it only goes from 0 to 0.54, which made me think it was treating the ending point as exclusive. To that end, i bumped it up to `np.arange(0, 0.56, 0.01)`, but then that returned everything up to 0.56.

Frankly, i'm not sure why that's happening (maybe a bug?), so here's an alternative that achieves the same result using np.linspace()

`np.linspace(0, 0.55, 56)`

Answer (score 5):

would go with

```
np.arange(0, 0.555, 0.01)
```

just took a look into the docs of numpy:

> End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out.
>   [numpy-docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

so the strange behaviour is caused by some float-rounding issue. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems for more info.

Comment: Nice, thanks for checking out the documentation to identify that this is caused by a float-rounding issue. Good to know.